# @FindBy and @FindAll returning Invocation error when accessing element

Tags: java, webdriver

I am running some WebDriver Test and was modifying some elements I want to use the @FindBy() page object annotation to generate the list WebElements. I can gather individual elements with no issue. I would like to utilize this to allow for cleaner code.

here is one implementation of the class:

```
 protected class InstElements extends PageBase{
    public InstElements(){
        super();
    }

    @FindAll(@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = ".skill-symbol.satisfactory.ng-scope"))
    public List<WebElement> satisfactoryLabels;
}
```

Second Implementation:

```
protected class InstElements extends PageBase{
    public InstElements(){
        super();
    }

    @FindBy(css = ".skill-symbol.satisfactory.ng-scope")
    public List<WebElement> satisfactoryLabels;
}
```

I receive the following Exception:

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.
```

I know I can just create a method a parse to a list like below (Works like a Charm):

```
 protected class InstElements extends PageBase{
    public InstElements(){
        super();
    }

    private static final String css_subject = ".skill-symbol.satisfactory.ng-scope")
    public List<WebElement> satisfactoryLabels(){

        return driver.findElements(By.cssSelector( css_subject ));
    }
}
```

But I would like to utilize the annotations because they provide cleaner code. Can someone please let me know what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was able to fix my own issue by re-invoking the class every time I use a call.

```
protected class InstElements extends PageBase{
    public InstElements(){
        super();
    }

    @FindBy(css = ".skill-symbol.satisfactory.ng-scope")
    public List<WebElement> satisfactoryLabels;
}
```

Instantiating on every use seemed to work and I mean EVERY USE!!

```
 InstElements test = new InstElements();
 int value = test.satisfactoryLabels.size();
```

This actually returns a number instead of an invocation error from the list